# Combining shapes doesn't work in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I've added *Combine Shapes* to my ribbon, as per [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150311101453/http://blogs.office.com/2012/03/20/creating-custom-shapes-in-powerpoint-2010/) on the MS Office blog.

I select the first shape, the second shape and... it remains inactive. Disabled.

When drawing new shapes, it works fine and I can combine shapes, intersect them and so on.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently, combining a shape only works when its text is empty. After deleting the text, everything worked fine. After combining I added the text back.